# intranet site in httpRequest class

Tags: java, salesforce, httprequest, apex-code

We are setting an intranet site in the setEndpoint in the httpRequest class. When the last line executes it  returns an error which says: System.CalloutException: Read timed out.
If I pass any other website like www.google.com this works perfectly fine. Any idea how to set the endpoint URL to a intranet site?

```
    string URL = 'some intranet website';
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(URL);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Comment: It should be exactly the same. In fact the application has no idea where the site is, it just forwards the request to your OS networking modules. Check that the site is accessible and does not require something extra (v.g. user validation)

Comment: Keep in mind that your site may be requiring authentication but, when accessed through web, automatically retrieve your credentials from Windows login or a Single Sign On.

Comment: If i paste that URL in the browser, the page gets loaded properly and I can see the content of that site. Also if I access this site from home, it doesn't open up. It only opens up in office... Not sure what can be done here...

Comment: To my knowledgeHttpRequest apex code would be executed on salesforce servers, not in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

All requests from Salesforce will be made from their well known pool of IP addresses.

1. Is your Intranet site available from outside? If you can paste the URL yourself in the browser it doesn't mean SF can access it! For example can you access your intranet from home (without using VPN, Citrix etc means)?
2. Read timeout can be increased. Set it to 1 minute and see what happens: `req.setTimeout(60000);`
3. If it still timeouts I suspect that the firewall is configured to just swallow the problems. Like a black hole, does not return you "Unauthorized, do you have username & password", nothing that reveals that this address is actually valid. Contact your network administrator and ask if he could whitelist [Salesforce IPs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm).
4. Of course you probably won't want to make it accessible for every Salesforce client. It's up to you if you need to pass some authentication mechanisms or will decide that you need a proxy. Proxy will be needed especially if your intranet site needs NTLM authentication (roughly speaking related to Windows domain - of course Salesforce servers won't sit in same LAN as your intranet server).